# google.Script.run not returning data on DOMContentLoaded execution

Tags: google-sheets-api

Hi not sure why this is not working I have set up some sample code to try and troubleshoot 
can someone help me in getting return data from the .gs function onSuccess. The populate JoyBox function does not have data. I have checked with the sample code. at developers.google and my code appears to be correct.

```js
function doGet() {
      //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page")
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page").evaluate();
    }


function findJoy() {
  return "Joy";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"   
integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Joy Machine</title>
      </head>
      
     <body>
     <p></p>
    <div class ="container">
    <div class = row>
    <div class  = col-10>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" >JoyBox</span> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id = "Joy" aria-label="Joy" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"  >
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"id = "More-" >
    </div>
       
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id = "UpdateBtn" >Update</button>
    </div> <!--col 6-->
    </div><!--row 6-->
    </div> <!--container-->
       
    <script>   
                function updateButtonclicked(){
                 alert("button Clicked")
                }
                 
                 function populateJoyBox(data){  
                     alert("data " ,data);
                     
                 } 
                 
               function getJoy(){
                      google.script.run
                       .withSuccessHandler(populateJoyBox)
                       .withFailureHandler(function(){alert("Fail");})
                       .findJoy(); 
      
                 } 
                 
      document.getElementById("UpdateBtn").addEventListener("click",updateButtonclicked);
        
     

    </script>
     <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
     <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getJoy);  
    </script>  
       
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
HTML "page" is:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Joy Machine</title>
  </head>

 <body>
 <p></p>
<div class ="container">
<div class = row>
<div class  = col-10>
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text" >JoyBox</span> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id = "Joy" aria-label="Joy" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"  >
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"id = "More-" >
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id = "UpdateBtn" >Update</button>
</div> <!--col 6-->
</div><!--row 6-->
</div> <!--container-->

<script>   
            function updateButtonclicked(){
             alert("button Clicked")
            }

             function populateJoyBox(data){  
                 alert("data " ,data);

             } 

           function getJoy(){
                  google.script.run
                   .withSuccessHandler(populateJoyBox)
                   .withFailureHandler(function(){alert("Fail");})
                   .findJoy(); 

             } 

  document.getElementById("UpdateBtn").addEventListener("click",updateButtonclicked);



</script>
 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
 <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getJoy);  
</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

I am looking for Joy ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are providing 2 parameters to the method [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), which can only have one:

```js
alert("data " ,data);
```

Because of this, only the first provided parameter (the string `"data"`) is shown in the alert.

You will notice that the parameter `data` is getting passed successfully to `populateJoyBox` if you try logging it.

#### Solution:

Concatenate the string and the variable like this:

```js
alert("data " + data);
```

#### Reference:

- [Window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)

Comment: Wow .. Thanks that was the issue ... sometimes it's the simple stuff

Comment: I should also add that I used this method to troubleshoot because Logger.log was not showing any results (perhaps because of the same construct)

Comment: @Cstrasser It's a client-side function, so `Logger.log` won't be of use. Use `console.log` and look for the value on the browser console.